# How to extend TextField to access model in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am writing a form post in ember.js.

- attr binding and condition only support boolean value other than expression.
- action didn't take arguments.

I want the error show only when the input get focus and the input is valid.

In simple way, I should do that in focus-in and focus-out property. But with so many field, I have to write two action for each input.

I want to write a reusable view to do that, but I don't know how to change model's value in view.

Any one know that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Erp.FromFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({

    attributeBindings: ['type', 'value', 'size', 'pattern', 'name', 'min', 'max',
                      'accept', 'autocomplete', 'autosave', 'formaction',
                      'formenctype', 'formmethod', 'formnovalidate', 'formtarget',
                      'height', 'inputmode', 'list', 'multiple', 'pattern', 'step',
                      'width', 'error', 'regex'],
    name: 'default',

    error: '',

    regex: '^.+$',

    isValid: true,


    valueChanged: function () {
        re = new RegExp(this.get('regex'), 'g');
        this.set('error', !re.test(this.get('value')));
    }.observes('value'),

    focusIn: function (event) {
        this._super(event);
        if (this.get('value') == undefined) {
            this.set('error', true);
        }
    },

    focusOut: function (event) {
        this._super(event);
        this.set('error', false);
    }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('form-field', Erp.FromFieldView);
```